# C# set button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue where the Button has the AccessibleDescription "1"

Tags: c#, button

Basically, i have a Matrix of Buttons where i want to play Battleships. If you click on a Button, the 2 Buttons under the clicked Button should go blue. I set the AccessibleDescription from 1-100 for each button in the matrix from left to right. So i want to talk the the Button under the clicked Button/Search for a Button with a specific AccessibleDescription.

Answer (score 0):

Group the buttons into panels and then call:

```
foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
{
   if (c is Button) ((Button)c).BackColor = Color.Blue;     
}
```

This will return a collection of controls contained within the panel, so you can get them.